# Check for duplicate record in Chrome Storage extension before saving

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a small Chrome extension that would allow me to save some records to chrome.storage and then display them.

I've managed to make the set and get process work as I wanted (kinda), but now I'd like to add a duplicate check before saving any record, and I'm quite stuck trying to find a nice and clean solution.

That's what I came up for now:

```
var storage = chrome.storage.sync;

function saveRecord(record) {
  var duplicate = false;
  var recordName = record.name;

  storage.get('records', function(data) {
    var records = data.records;
    console.log('im here');

    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
      var Record = records[i];
      if (Record.name === recordName) {
        duplicate = true;
        break;
      } else {
        console.log(record);
      }
    }

    if (duplicate) {
      console.log('this record is already there!');
    } else {
      arrayWithRecords.push(record);

      storage.set({ bands: arrayWithRecords }, function() {
        console.log('saved ' + record.name);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I'm basically iterating on the array containing the records and checking if the name property already exists. The problem is it breaks basic set and get functionality -- in fact, when saving it correctly logs `'im here'` and the relative record object, but it doesn't set the value. Plus, after a while (generally after trying to list the bands with a basic `storage.get` function) it returns this error:

> Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'name' of null

I'm guessing this is due to the async nature of the set and get and my incompetence working with it, but I can't get my head around it in order to find a better alternative. Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you try to log the results of the `storage.get` operation (i.e. `data`) what do you get ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem It returns the object containing my records array, with the new record set to null; then, after a while, it breaks with the TypeError reported in the main question.

Comment: Could you post the actual object (`data`) as you see it in the console log ? Also, what do you mean by "after a while" ? Does it work as expected for some time and then it breaks ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem here is the screenshot since posting an object tree in the comments is quite hard :D -> http://svel.to/b1u (*bands* equals *records* in the main question, and the first band object is an old record). It does **not** work as expected, it doesn't save any record. It just doesn't returns errors and keeps logging and outputting stuff for a few seconds after trying to save some record. Then, when trying to list the records with a simple get and log function it breaks. Thanks for the help, anyway!

Comment: @ExpertSystem magically solved the bug. I can't reproduce it anymore. Sorry and thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: This is what I believe happened: The problem was that (somehow) you had introduced a `null` entry in your array (so `Record.name` throwed an error). After emtying the storage (e.g. by uninstalling and re-installing the extension) the problem got away :)

Comment: Got the same problem with my extension. But it appears only after a week at some point. Reinstalling helps but it returns back after a while....